# Kong Ingress Controller: prevent stripping the path when routing the request to a service

Tags: kubernetes, api-gateway, kong, ingress-controller, kong-ingress

I'm learning Kong API Gateway, in particular the installation on Kubernetes with the Kong Ingress Controller, and I've completed [this tutorial](https://docs.konghq.com/kubernetes-ingress-controller/2.12.x/guides/getting-started/).

## TL;DR

The HTTP request I send:

```
GET 127.0.0.1:80/weather/London
```

The HTTP request the service receives:

```
GET 127.0.0.1:3000/London
```

When sending an HTTP request to a Kong service, how can I route the request, so that the full path of the URL is preserved, **without stripping the first part** (`/weather`)?

## Long version

I'm trying to create a Node.js microservice that provides an API to retrieve the weather: the API is called with /weather/:countryName and returns a JSON with weather information (using [OpenWeatherAPIs](https://openweathermap.org/api)).

#### Example

Sending the following request

```
curl -i localhost:3000/weather/London
```

Return the following JSON:

```
{
    "cityName": "London (GB)",
    "temperature": {
        "actual": 14.31,
        "min": 12.56,
        "max": 15.71
    },
    "humidity": 81,
    "windSpeed": 3.09,
    "description": "broken clouds",
    "iconURL": "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/04d@2x.png"
}
```

### Kong

My setup is the one from the tutorial I linked previously:

- local cluster with minikube;
- minikube tunnel (docker driver) running in background;

#### Service and Deployment resources

File `weather.yml`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: weather
  name: weather
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 1025
    name: tcp
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 1025
  - port: 1026
    name: udp
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 1026
  - port: 3000
    name: http
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 3000
  selector:
    app: weather
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: weather
  name: weather
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: weather
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: weather
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: mikyll/api-weather:v1.0
        name: weather
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
        env:
          - name: NODE_NAME
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: spec.nodeName
          - name: POD_NAME
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: metadata.name
          - name: POD_NAMESPACE
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: metadata.namespace
          - name: POD_IP
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: status.podIP
        resources: {}
```

Applied with `cat .\weather.yml | kubectl apply -f -`

#### Routing Configuration

File `weather-routing.yml`

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: weather-route
  annotations:
    konghq.com/strip-path: 'false'
spec:
  ingressClassName: kong
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /weather
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: weather
            port:
              number: 3000
```

Applied with `cat .\weather-routing.yml | kubectl apply -f -`

### Problem

When I send a request to the proxy, the first part of the URL is removed when calling the service:

```
curl -i 127.0.0.1:80/weather/London
```

Gives the following result:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot GET /London</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

### Question

How can I pass the same path, without stripping the first part (`/weather`) to the service?

Comment: Did you notice the glaring `konghq.com/strip-path: 'true'` annotation in your Ingress?

Comment: @Botje absolutely not :')

Comment: @Botje I tried setting it to 'false' and updating the configuration with `kubectl apply` but nothing changed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem was that I had mistakenly created **2 routes**:
"weather" and "weather-route":

```
PS D:\kong-kubernetes> kubectl get ingress
NAME            CLASS   HOSTS          ADDRESS     PORTS   AGE
weather         kong    *              127.0.0.1   80      3h9m
weather-route   kong    *              127.0.0.1   80      25m
```

Therefore, when editing "weather-route", even if I set `konghq.com/strip-path` to `'false'`, the other route rule had it set to `'true'` and was getting applied earlier, causing the request to fail.

Removing it fixed the issue:

```
kubectl delete ingress weather
```

```
PS D:\kong-kubernetes> kubectl get ingress
NAME            CLASS   HOSTS          ADDRESS     PORTS   AGE
weather-route   kong    *              127.0.0.1   80      25m
```

HTTP request:

```
PS D:\kong-kubernetes> curl -i 127.0.0.1:80/weather/London

{
    "cityName": "London (GB)",
    "temperature": {
        "actual": 14.53,
        "min": 12.64,
        "max": 15.76
    },
    "humidity": 79,
    "windSpeed": 5.66,
    "description": "scattered clouds",
    "iconURL": "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/03d@2x.png"
}
```

---

A special thanks to [Botje](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1548468/botje) for making me notice the first most important issue :)